# how do I power my motor shield without an arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield, robotics

I want to power my motor shield without my UNO. I have connected the `+ve` and `-ve` terminals resulting in lighting up of the LED.

Is there any way to control the motors in this arrangement from the Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking because what you are trying to do doesn't make much sense.

The motors connected to the motor shield are controlled by the output pins of the Arduino that the motor shield is plugged in to.

You could run jumper leads from an separate Arduino into your unplugged motor shield, but that's just extending what you already have.  You really do need some form of controller, not necessary a microprocessor, otherwise how can you go forwards and backwards?

Is the problem you have put the Arduino into a plastic case and you can't plug the motor shield in any more?  If so get a set of long male to female connectors (they look like the Arduino connectors) and use them as extensions.

Is the problem you have a different format of board and can't plug it in? If so use the wires method to form the correct connections.

I hope that answers your question, if not please try and explain what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer and yes my problem actually is I cant plug in the motor shield directly. so i wanted to know is it necessary to connect all the pins or only some of them will do the work

Comment: Right - Order some connectors something like (http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-header-10pin?utm_source=google&utm_medium=googleshopping&utm_campaign=googlebase&gclid=CJym0NK4nc0CFeIp0wodDAoKMQ) you need two different lengths.  OR connect ribbon cables/wires from the Arduino to the Shield and that should sort it out.

Comment: Which all pins should i connect ??

Comment: Only some of them do the work but you would need to look it up in your datasheet for the shield because they can be different.  You also have to remember to connect the grounds together on your two supplies (only -ve not +ve!!) otherwise things won't work.  Whats the shield make and model?

Comment: I have a motor shield with L293D micro-controller

Comment: Thanks a lot I will check out the datasheet and try to figure out. Thanks a lot

Comment: Since you have not revealed exactly WHICH motor shield you are asking about, nobody can answer your question. It depends on exactly how YOUR motor shield is designed.  It does not benefit you to withhold the identity of the board you are asking about. It makes it impossible for us to help you.

Comment: I have a motor shield by DK electronics